# Libcurl ftp wildcard upload

Tags: c, ftp, libcurl

Hi how do you upload multiple files using a wildcard with libcurl? Eg, I created three files, 
`file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt`. I want to upload these files with `"file"` in their name, using a wildcard something like `file*`. I'm using C by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code that iterates over the local files, then you use libcurl to upload them one by one.